# How to use entity relationship to get count difference of arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, core-data

Let's say I have data model with entities Department and Role with relationship `Department<-->>Role`. In my UI I currently display department1 and in a tableview list other departments (e.g. department2, department3...).

I'm trying to get a bunch of arrays: one per Role each Department has. I can get an array of Role by the displayed department1 by fetchrequest and predicate but can't figure out how to get an array of Role for each Department in the tableview. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First, you do not need arrays. Core data is best managed by a `NSFetchedResultsController` - this works best with a table view. Also, most likely you will not need any fetch requests.

To get all roles in a department, simply call your relationship name:

```
department1.roles
```

The result is an `NSSet` which is not ordered. You can order it, e.g. alphabetically like this

```
department1.roles.sortedArrayUsingSortDescriptors(
 [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name" ascending: true)]
)
```

If you want to display the departments in the table sections and the roles in the rows, you would use a `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch the `Role` entity specifying a `sectionNameKeyPath` indicating the department (e.g. name).